# Removal of ( ) from string in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

We are receiving data like tx=Reach % (YouTube) and we need only Youtube from that. How can we remove without hardcoding. For hardcoding i was using

df=df.withColumn('tx', F.regexp_replace('tx', 'Reach % (YouTube)', 'YouTube'))

but we do not need hardcoding like youtube or etc.How can we apply checks like of there is Reach % then remove all except string inside bracket in pyspark

Answer (score 0):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("tx=Reach % (YouTube)", )],
    schema=['col1']
)
df.show(10, False)
+--------------------+
|col1                |
+--------------------+
|tx=Reach % (YouTube)|
+--------------------+


df.select(func.regexp_extract(func.col('col1'), '\((.*?)\)', 1).alias('val')).show(10, False)
+-------+
|val    |
+-------+
|YouTube|
+-------+
```

Comment: I have different values in column like Reach % \(Facebook\),Reach % \(GDN\) but it took YouTube only.I am using 
df=df.withColumn("MediaNm", when(col("MediaNm").like("%Reach%"),F.regexp_extract(F.col("MediaNm"), r"\((.*?)\)", 1)))

Comment: it made all values to YouTube in column MediaNm. Expected was like when there is Reach % (Facebook) in record for column medianm then it should convert to Facebook

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_extract` instead of `regexp_replace`

```
df.withColumn("tx", F.regexp_extract(F.col("tx"), r"\(([\w]+)\)", 1))
```

- `\(` is `(`
- `\)` is `)`
- `[\w]+` is 1 or more word characters like `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`.

Note that this will only extract word characters. If you want to extract anything between parenthesis, you can use `.*?` instead of `[\w]+`.

Comment: It made all values to YouTube in column Media Nm.  I am using  validated_df=validated_df.withColumn("MediaNm", when(col("MediaNm").like("%Reach%"),F.regexp_extract(F.col("MediaNm"), r"\((.*?)\)", 1)))...Expected was like when there is Reach % (Facebook) in record for column medianm then it should convert to Facebook. when there is Reach % (YouTube) in record for column medianm then it should convert to YouTube @PeterSmith